# How do I access global css variable in webcomponent

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, web-component

I am using vanilla webcomponents and bundle with webpack.

In my components css I import the global css sheet with the @import declaration e.g

```
@import "../../style.css";
```

In style.css I have my variable defined e.g

```
:root {--variable: rgba(236, 236, 233, 0.0);}
```

From my component I can access other css declarations in the global style.css, but seemingly not the variable. e.g. this does not work for me in the components css:

```
background-color: var(--variable);
```

Neither does it seem to work when trying to access the variable from js e.g.

```
element.style.border = "2px solid var(--variable)";
```

Is this a limitation of the webcomponent technology / webpack or is there another way to access / define the global css variable so it is accessible inside the web component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok..  Asking the question, inspired the solution.. Rubber Duck!

I will leave the question, as I was not able to find a solution elsewhere and someone might have the same issue.

I do not have the technical explanation (anybody who has is very welcome to elaborate), but defining global variables for access in webcomponents in a global stylesheet, should be inside the :host pseudo class and not in :root as [per the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) for global properties.

This will work:

```
:host {--variable: rgba(236, 236, 233, 0.0);}
```

Or at least: it works for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate?

CSS variables from Global CSS are available all the way *down* the DOM, including shadowDOM

```html
<style>
  :root {
    --var1: red;
  }

  body {
    --var2: gold;
  }
</style>

<my-component></my-component>

<script>
  customElements.define("my-component", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super()
        .attachShadow({mode: "open"})
        .innerHTML = `<style>
                      :host{
                        display:block;
                        background: var(--var1);
                        color: var(--var2);
                      }
                      </style>
                      <h1>Hello Web Component World!</h1>`;
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Yes. That's what I would have expected, but for some reason it does not work in my context? I can see the variable correctly in devtools, but it does not compute. Moving it to :host in the global css sheet did the trick, for a reason beyond my knowledge.  Pls see my answer below. Pls. note that I have my web components in separate files bundled with webpack for deployment, so your example is in a different context.

Comment: Create a minimal failing example in your question with the [<>] button in the SO editor.

Comment: Will do when time hits my way. Even a minimal example will require package.json, postcss.config.js, webpack.json and several files in a folder hierarchy. Being in the pragmatic corner ATM I'll stick to whatever works ;)